# Why does not display the Toolbar?

Tags: java, android, layout, toolbar, android-appbarlayout

My activity_main.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        app:title="@string/app_name">
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The problem is, that the Toolbar is not displayed. But whenever I surround it with the following Element, it is displayed:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
```

What is a AppBarLayout?!

I appresiate every help,

LG M:)

Comment: You might want to look at this https://stackoverflow.com/q/31328695/6272369

Answer (score 1):

[follow the official doc to know more about appbarlayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout)

AppBarLayout is a vertical LinearLayout which implements many of the features of material designs app bar concept, namely scrolling gestures.

Children should provide their desired scrolling behavior through setScrollFlags(int) and the associated layout xml attribute: app:layout_scrollFlags.

This view depends heavily on being used as a direct child within a CoordinatorLayout. If you use AppBarLayout within a different ViewGroup, most of it's functionality will not work.

AppBarLayout also requires a separate scrolling sibling in order to know when to scroll. The binding is done through the AppBarLayout.ScrollingViewBehavior behavior class, meaning that you should set your scrolling view's behavior to be an instance of AppBarLayout.ScrollingViewBehavior. A string resource containing the full class name is available.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.mgh.jaatrabackoffice.activity.DashboardActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_dashboard" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_date_range_white_24dp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:backgroundTint="#ffbb33"/>
```

and if you want a custom toolbar use this code instead of toolbar

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?android:actionBarSize"
android:background="#e91e63"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/back_imagebtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_back_button" /> <!--android:tint="#e91e63"-->
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/usericon_imagebtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/user"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:tint="#fff"/>
</LinearLayout>

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0.5dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white"/>
```

Comment: And how can I avoid using such a AppBarLayout in my excaple? Why is the toolbar not visible?

Comment: you can design custom toolbar or else just use toolbar inside `appbarlayout`

Comment: and which attributes should I use in an custom Toolbar?

Comment: i'm giving it in my previous answer

Comment: i've given it .. hit correct answer if it worked for you .. thank you @justMe